# Hidden singleton to encapsulate initialization and destruction code

Tags: c++, singleton, c++14

I have a library that requires manual initialization and destruction, and I'd like to make that process automatic. Since both the init and quit functions should only be called once I thought a good solution would be to use a singleton, but since calling `Singleton::instance().func()` is annoying to call for each function, I implemented the Singleton in the cpp file and used functions in the header as a wrapper for the singletons methods.

**Framework.h**

```
namespace framework {
    //void init(); // want this to be automatic.
    //void quit(); 

    float func1();
    void func2(int i);
    //...
}
```

**Framework.cpp**

```
namespace framework
{
    class Framework
    {
    private:
        Framework() {
            //init code
            //...
        }

        ~Framework() {
            //quit code
            //...
        }

    public:
        Framework(const Framework&)            = delete;
        Framework& operator=(const Framework&) = delete;

        static Framework& instance() {
            static Framework result; //on first call initialization code is run.
            return result;
        }

        float func1() {
            //...
        }

        void func2(int i) {
            //...
        }
    };

    // wrapper functions
    float func1() {
         return Framework::instance().func1();
    }

    void func2(int i) {
        Framework::instance().func2(i);
    }
}
```

Are there any problems with this design, besides the general problems that can occur when using a regular singleton?

Comment: You have no control over lifetime of such singleton. You may want to call `quit` automatically, but calling `init` automatically makes no sense. Also it might be a good idea to set up a boolean static variable to check whether Framework was initialized already or not.

Comment: Whats wrong with calling init automatically? I can't use the other functions before the initialization, and it will only be called once during the first call.

Comment: There are at least two things wrong with calling `init` automatically: 1) each call of `instance()` method will involve overhead of branching to check boolean variable implicitly created by compiler to control local static variable initialization (this is actually a good reason to never use local static variables); 2) this one is a bit difficult to explain, but explicit control over `init` and (potentially automatic) `uninit` scope makes scope at which calls to library methods (and therefore objects calling them) are allowed explicit as well; and implicit < explicit

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any problems with this design ...

Well, there's a chance that the linker clashes with ambiguities of another class `framework::Framework` declared/defined elsewhere.

You should rather encapsulate that singleton into an anonymous/unnamed namespace in the translation unit:

```
namespace { // <<<< Guarantees that everything within this is only 
            // visible within this translation unit, even when linking that code.
    class Framework
    {
    private:
        Framework() {
            //init code
            //...
        }

        ~Framework() {
            //quit code
            //...
        }

    public:
        Framework(const Framework&)            = delete;
        Framework& operator=(const Framework&) = delete;

        static Framework& instance() {
            static Framework result; //on first call initialization code is run.
            return result;
        }

        float func1() {
            //...
        }

        void func2(int i) {
            //...
        }
    };
}
```

---

```
namespace framework
{
    // wrapper functions
    float func1() {
         return Framework::instance().func1();
    }

    void func2(int i) {
        Framework::instance().func2(i);
    }
}
```